# How to write this SQL query in VB.NET LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

How can I write this SQL query in VB.NET LINQ?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT_NO
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.SERIAL_NO IN (SELECT MAX (A.SERIAL_NO ) 
                       FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID 
                       GROUP BY A.SUBJECT_ID)
AND B.STATUS = 'N';
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the usage of `group by` in your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the reasonably direct C# conversion would be something like:

```
var validSerialNumbers = from a in dbContext.A
                         join b in dbContext.B on a.ID equals b.ID
                         group a.SerialNo by a.SubjectId into g
                         select g.Max();

var query = from a in dbContext.A
            join b in dbContext.B on a.ID equals b.ID
            where validSerialNumbers.Contains(a.SerialNo)
            where b.Status == "N"
            select new { a, b };

var count = query.Count();
```

I would imagine you could convert that to VB pretty similar. Unfortunately Reflector doesn't do a good job on this one, but the clauses should convert 1-for-1 as far as I'm aware.